# SharePoint get items change event by HTTP Request

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

currently Im trying to get SharePoint list item event change by HTTP Request.

The Request URL im using:
`https://{{SHarePoint Tenant ID}}.sharepoint.com/sites/{{SHarePoint Site Name}}/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('List1')/RootFolder/GetListItemChanges`

Request Body:

```
{
    "query": {
        "Add": true
    }
}
```

[image: The result return]

Even I created a new record on the SharePoint List and call this request again, still it will always return a empty Array like the screen cap above.

Is that the SP.ChangeQuery not work like this? If not, how can I get a item event change by HTTP request?

Thank you.